# Trying to figure out lighttpd and rewriting URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

So i have a website that uses a system like this:

`domain.com/?page=123`

that i want to display as:

`domain.com/123`

I have 4 virtual hosts, so i ony want to apply this to one of them.

My virtualhost setup is as follows:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)domain1\.org$" {
-settings-
}
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)domain2\.org$" {
-settings-
}
```

I really have no clue and tried searching already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tagged this as rewrite, so you know it involves rewrite, which is correct. Have you read up on lighttpd's [mod_rewrite](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite)? Did you have some difficulty understanding it?

Comment: I do have difficulty understanding it, but i can't get it to work inside my virtual hosts.

Comment: You can't get it to work, what have you tried? How did you apply the rewrite? Did it do anything? Care to show the rewrite code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the correct host block, you'll want:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/(.*)$" => "/?page=$1" )
```

Which is a regular expression saying, match beginning of line `^` followed by `/` followed by anything 
`.*`, and catch it in a subexpression `(.*)` to the end of the line `$` and rewrite it to `/?page=<the subexpression text>`

Since you'll have it inside the $HTTP["host"] block it'll only apply to a specific host.

Edit: Example log

```
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.300) -- splitting Request-URI 
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.301) Request-URI  :  /123 
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.302) URI-scheme   :  http 
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.303) URI-authority:  rewrite.example.com 
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.304) URI-path     :  /123 
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.305) URI-query    :   
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.300) -- splitting Request-URI 
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.301) Request-URI  :  /?page=123 
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.302) URI-scheme   :  http 
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.303) URI-authority:  rewrite.example.com 
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.304) URI-path     :  / 
2013-06-21 12:07:52: (response.c.305) URI-query    :  page=123
```

In this example `/123` gets rewritten to `/?page=123` and we see the request restart on `/?page=123`

Comment: Using these settings, going to "domain.org/123" gives me 404. "domain.org/?page=123" still works. I inserted this after my document.root setting.

Comment: @GuploaderUpload add `debug.log-request-handling = "enable"` to your config, also make sure `server.errorlog = "<a file you have access to>"` and look at the error log. It gives significant information about how the request is handled. I'd guess the rewrite rule isn't being applied for whatever reason if you're getting a 404.